# How can I set default options selected during dropdown initialization not in HTML using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget by Eric Hynds?

Tags: jquery

How can I set default options selected during dropdown initialization not in HTML? I am pulling selected values/options from database and want to make them selected every time I open the dropdown for changes. I am using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget by Eric Hynds.

```
var PreSelectedValuesDatabase = “Material in alternative formats (e.g., large print, Braille, e-text):Periodic, Accessible building access (e.g., keyless entry, accessible parking):Periodic, Ergonomics Assessment:Permanent”;
$("#GroupDropDown").multiselect(
            {                   
                height:500, 
                minWidth:500,
                selectedList:false, 
                open: function(event, ui){
                        console.log(event);
                },
                close: function(event, ui){
                           var values = $(this).val();                             
                    }                   
            });
```

```html
  <select id='GroupDropDown' name="example-optgroup" multiple="multiple" size="1">
   <optgroup label="Material in alternative formats (e.g., large print, Braille, e-text)">
    <option value="Material in alternative formats (e.g., large print, Braille, e-text):Permanent">Permanent</option>
    <option value="Material in alternative formats (e.g., large print, Braille, e-text):Periodic">Periodic</option>
    <option value="Material in alternative formats (e.g., large print, Braille, e-text):Temporary">Temporary</option>
    <option value="Material in alternative formats (e.g., large print, Braille, e-text):Unknown">Unknown</option>
   </optgroup>
  
   <optgroup label="Accessible building access (e.g., keyless entry, accessible parking)">
    <option value="Accessible building access (e.g., keyless entry, accessible parking):Permanent">Permanent</option>
    <option value="Accessible building access (e.g., keyless entry, accessible parking):Periodic">Periodic</option>
    <option value="Accessible building access (e.g., keyless entry, accessible parking):Temporary">Temporary</option>
    <option value="Accessible building access (e.g., keyless entry, accessible parking):Unknown">Unknown</option>
   </optgroup>
   
   <optgroup label="Ergonomics Assessment">
    <option value="Ergonomics Assessment:Permanent">Permanent</option>
    <option value="Ergonomics Assessment:Periodic">Periodic</option>
    <option value="Ergonomics Assessment:Temporary">Temporary</option>
    <option value="Ergonomics Assessment:Unknown">Unknown</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#GroupDropDown').on('change',function(e){
  var id = e.target.value;
  if(id == PreSelectedValuesDatabase){
      $('#GroupDropDown 
     option[value="'+PreSelectedValuesDatabase+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
})
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It doesn't checked any check boxes.